# Where can I find information on the Html class in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syntax

Please can anyone tell me all the properties or methods which I can use while using the following method of `Html` syntax:

```
<%=  Html.TextBox("email", "", new { maxlength = 200 })%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("email", "*")%>
```

I want the link where I can get the complete syntax of the above.

Comment: There's a synatx error in your title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pretty much anything that prints something out, even methods which return numbers, strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is always your best bet for things like this.

[Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox.aspx)

[Validation message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx)

Here is one for the whole Html namespace:
[Html namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.aspx)